# A regex to find number only but not followed by test in a String

Tags: regex

I have a string as "Test me for find this [test$12345] and dont find [test$SS7890]this". I have to find only 12345 and not 7890.

Comment: `/\[test\$(\d+)\]/` https://regex101.com/r/pU1hY7/1

Comment: Add more clarity to your requirement and show what you've tried

Comment: thanks for your help.. but it will give me [test$12345] but i need only part of that string which is only number like '12345' only.. can you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will:

- match the digits between `[test$` and `]`

The regex:

```
(?<=\[test\$)([0-9]+(?=]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Example**

https://regex101.com/r/bY1kH8/3

## Explained

```
(?<=\[test\$) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
\[ matches the character [ literally
test matches the characters test literally (case sensitive)
\$ matches the character $ literally
1st Capturing group ([0-9]+(?=]))
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
(?=]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
] matches the character ] literally
```